# How to get data from Route or ActivatedRoute when subscribing to router.events.subscribe in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get the data from a Router whenever the Route changes but I'm not having success. Here I set the `asdf` property

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '' },
      { component: LoginComponent, path: 'login' },
      {
        children: [
          { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'overview', data: { asdf: 'hello' } },
          { component: OverviewComponent, path: 'overview', data: { asdf: 'hello' } },
        ], component: DashboardComponent,
        path: '',
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here I can get the URL from the router when the route changes but `asdf` is undefined :(

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'cs-map',
  styleUrls: ['map.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  private routerSub;

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let url = val.url;
        console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['asdf']); // data is defined but asdf is not :(
      }
    });
  }
}
```

How can I get `asdf`'s value?

Edit: I'm navigating to `/overview`

Comment: I think that's a known issue. Can you try with `setTimeout(() => console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['asdf']))`?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: There was a similar question today where someone suggested using `Observable.zip()` with `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data` and `this.router.events`.

Comment: Do you mean this?:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md

Comment: Exactly . . . . . . .

Comment: Do I need to replace the router.events.subscribe with Observable.zip? I'm not exactly sure how to go from here

Comment: I don't know. I just saw it mentioned on a similar question. I'm not using TS myself and don't have deep knowledge about observables.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router, 
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
{

 this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
        .map(route => route.firstChild)
        .switchMap(route => route.data)
        .map(data => data['asdf'])
}
```

1. For every events from router, I filter only NavigationEnd event
2. Then I map this event to the activatedRoute (because I want to read the value of activatedRoute on NavigationEnd).
3. I map the activatedRoute to the firstChild (first children declared with RouterModule.forRoot()).
4. Then a switchMap is made to get the data of this route, a switchMap because data is an observable.
5. Finally I map the data object to the key I want, in this case asdf

Comment: For every events from `router`, I filter only `NavigationEnd` event, then I map this event to the `activatedRoute` (because I want to read the value of `activatedRoute` on `NavigationEnd`). I map the `activatedRoute` to the `firstChild` (first children declared with `RouterModule.forRoot()`). Then a `switchMap` is made to get the data of this route, a switchMap because data is an observable. Finally I map the `data` object to the key I want, in this case `asdf`

Comment: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'` it's probably because of angular 6's and rxjs 6's change. could you post updated code?

Comment: Does not seem to work for activated routes inside lazy-loaded modules...

Comment: this subscription never fires. Not when the route changes. Not when the params change. Any ideas?

Comment: For lazy loaded routes, this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308911/4123995 - basically we need to keep going deeper into `firstChild` of every route until the very bottom.

Answer (score 18):

The following is updated to work with rxjs v6

```
constructor(private router: Router, 
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
{

   this.router.events
        .pipe(
         filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
         map(() => this.activatedRoute),
         map(route => route.firstChild),
         switchMap(route => route.data),
         map(data => data['asdf']))
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a modified example using @Neelavar [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836466/7678417) example.

It might look long but it's simple, be patient, if you stick through it, it should work. Just following the steps outlined should take a few minutes.

## Full Explanation for my setup, for beginners

#### You should already know how to create components and setup routing, I won't explain that in depth.

### 1. Setup Data Property in Routes Array

In your routes array (you will find this either in **app.module.ts** or **app-routes.module.ts** or in some cases a **routes.ts** file).

If you can't find this, check basic routing setup in:

- [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)
- [a video as well](https://youtu.be/Np3ULAMqwNo)

**a basic setup is all you need!**

#### Add the data property like so (you will need to generate the home component):

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: {title: 'home'} },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' },
];
```

### 2. Create a class

**RouteData.ts**, I have it in the same folder space as **app.module.ts**

```
export class RouteData {
  title: string;
}
```

This is just to add types for using the observable in typescript, the IDE can then autocomplete *"title"* or *"id"* or *"animation"* for me if I add that to the data class later.

### 3. Import the following into app.component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RouteData } from './route-data';
```

Then above the **constructor** code, declare the variable

```
routeData$: Observable<RouteData>;
```

Then inside the **constructor**

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}
```

### 4. Then inside **constructor again**

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {

    this.routeData$ = router.events.pipe(
      filter(routeEvent => routeEvent instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => activatedRoute),
      map(activatedRoute => activatedRoute.firstChild),
      switchMap(firstChild => firstChild.data),
      map((data: RouteData) => data)
      );

  }
```

Explanation of code adapted from @Tuizi [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41902374/7678417) Example Comment:

- For every event from router, filter only for the **NavigationEnd** event *(when the router has completed navigation)*.
- Then map (return) the currently activatedRoute.
- Map the activatedRoute to the firstChild (The first child of this route in the router state tree).
- Then a switchMap emits the data of this route, use a switchMap because each "data" that is  emitted is an observable, the switch map will cancel the old observable when a new one is emitted, saving memory.
- Map (return) the data object, assign it a type of RouteData.
- Finally you can use this Observable in a template using async pipe

```
    <span *ngIf="routeData$ | async as routeData">
        {{ routeData.title | titlecase }}
      </span>
```

*A note: "async as" breaks type checking in the template at the moment :(

[github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24598)

Comment: The 4th step should be done in the constructor, otherwise there is a chance to miss the navigation events.

Answer (score 7):

If you are hitting the route the first time you load the route in your browser, ActivatedRoute will have the current data. But if you then click on something which causes a second router navigation, the ActivatedRoute instance for that second route will have the original route's information. This could be due to to the fact that it was the ActivatedRoute at the time it was injected into the constructor.

However there is an updated instance of ActivatedRouteSnapshot associated with the ActivationEnd event, so you can access the data like this:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
    map(event => (<ActivationEnd>event).snapshot),
    map(snapshot => (<ActivatedRouteSnapshot>snapshot).data)).subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data from the NEW route: ' + data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

data in the routes must be an array of objects rather than just object so define them like this

```
{ component: LoginComponent, path: 'login', data:[{myKey1: myValue1}] },
```

Now to retrieve it use this code in your components constructor

```
constructor(private router:Router, private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute) {

  router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .map(_ => this.router.routerState.root)
    .map(route => {
      while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
      return route;
    })
  .flatMap(route => route.data)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data[0].myKey1);

    });

}
```

Comment: This is not what the interface suggests:

Comment: ```export declare type Data = {
    [name: string]: any;
};```

Comment: @MildFuzz it dosent suggest otherwise too it means ```Data```  which is alias of ```data``` is of type ```any``` which can be an array too.   but if you subscribe to router.events and check on the type you see that its an arraay

Comment: If you are using the data in a child component then the while loop here helps get the edge route ( where the data is ).